# BEGINNER - Printf don't print the entire word of my code

Tags: c, printf

```
int main() {

    char letra = 'B';
    int numero = 10;
    float virgulas = 10.5;
    char casa = 'Esquina';

    printf("%c \n",letra);
    printf("%d \n",numero);
    printf("%f \n",virgulas);

    printf("Letra %c, numero %d, em uma %c\n", letra, numero, casa);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run my code, "Esquina" appears as a random number every time.

Comment: `char casa = "Esquina"` should cause the compiler to issue a warning. It doesn't do what you (apparently) think it does.

Comment: `"Esquina"` is a string not a character, you will need to store it in a `char*` and then print it with `%s`

Comment: I recommend you read a tutorial on data types, `char` can only hold 1 character

Comment: @Fanarosss so %c is only for single words, and %s for multiple words?

Comment: @RodrigoH %c is for single characters

Comment: `char casa = 'Esquina';` is flawed — you can only store a single character in a single character variable.  What you get is implementation defined.  Multiple character literals are permitted, but the standard doesn't say how they're interpreted.  When you print a single character with `%c`, you geta single character output.  You probably need `const char *casa = "Esquina";` or `char casa[] = "Esquina";` (we don't have enough information to choose between them) and use `%s` in the format string.  And read your C book to work out why.

Comment: You should probably [find a good beginners book to read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead of asking questions here about really basic stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"Esquina"` is a string. You need to store it in a `char*` (not a `char` - most modern compilers should issue an error on this mistake):

```
char* casa = "Esquina";
```

You can then print it out with the `%s` formatter (not `%c`):

```
printf("Letra %c, numero %d, em uma %s\n", letra, numero, casa);
/* Here -----------------------------^ */
```

Comment: Shouldn't he `malloc` memory for the pointer first and then assign `Esquina` with `strcpy` ??

Comment: @Fanarosss: No, not really.  You could do that; there is no need to do that (and it is unnecessarily complicated for this example code).  You could use `char casa[] = "Eqsuina";` too — it would work.  There's not enough information to choose between them.

Comment: Note that `char casa = 'Esquina';` might generate a warning but is not formally an error.  The result is implementation defined — the implementation might define that it is an error, but isn't obliged to do so.

Comment: I tried what you said and the result is very weird

    `B
    10
    10.500000
    Letra B, numero 10, em uma #9Zýï├¢³®¤Ó6>N²eìK¦æ
    kE┬¸í#çjf&il╣³┘o]õ╣Ã«äç?£=¸ÏÊBw>¤|­ËH¨½be\?
    Ì»╬¹P3■míÖù<▄dÙ%ù·_yÐ&R┘Þ‗íô Ô{■¹` @Mureinik

Comment: @RodrigoH I tried the recommended changes and the last line of the output is `Letra B, numero 10, em uma Esquina`.

Comment: It's working now, thanks guys.

I am reading a book for beginners, and it was very helpful this topic for me.

Answer (score 2):

First, some basics:

In C, a *string* is a sequence of character values followed by a 0-valued terminator.  Strings are stored in *arrays* of `char`, not single `char` objects.

A *string literal* is delimited by double quotes (`"`), while *character constants* are delimited by single quotes (`'`).

In your code

```
char casa = 'Esquina';
```

you declare `casa` as a `char`, meaning it can only store a single character value, not a string.  You initialize it with `'Esquina'`, which is not a string literal, but a *multibyte character constant*.  Multibyte character constants are mapped on to `char` objects in an implementation-defined manner.  In this particular case, it's not what you want.

`casa` should be declared as either

```
const char *casa = "Esquina";
```

or

```
char casa[] = "Esquina";
```

depending on whether or not you will need to modify the contents of the string later on.  The first version declares `casa` as a pointer to the first character in the *string literal* `"Esquina"`<sup>1</sup>.  The second version declares `casa` as a 8-element array of `char`<sup>2</sup> and copies the contents of the string literal to it, giving us

```
casa[0] == 'E'
casa[1] == 's'
casa[2] == 'q'
casa[3] == 'u'
casa[4] == 'i'
casa[5] == 'n'
casa[6] == 'a'
casa[7] == 0
```

To print it out, you'd use the `%s` conversion specifier in `printf`:

```
printf("Letra %c, numero %d, em uma %s\n", letra, numero, casa);
```

---

1. String literals are stored as arrays of `char` such that the array is allocated when the program starts up and released when the program terminates.  Attempting to modify the contents of a string literal invokes undefined behavior - it may work, it may cause a segfault, it may do something unexpected.  To prevent us from accidentally modifying the string literal through `casa`, we declare it as `const char *`; this way, any attempt to change the string will cause the compiler to yak.

   The size is taken from the length of the string, plus an additional element to store the string terminator.